# Intersecting lists with custom comparer returns empty set

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I am comparing to list using intersect as follows: 
(Using POCO Car as an example)

```
IEnumerable<Car> updatedCars = CarsList.Intersect(dbCarsList, carsComperator);
```

I defined carsComperator as follows

```
public bool Equals(Car x, Car y)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
    if (x == null || y == null) return false;
    return (x.Id == y.Id);
}

public int GetHashCode(Car car)
{
    return car.Id.GetHashCode();  // Id is Guid
}
```

But when Intersect command runs it brings nothing.
I assume that the program does not pass throgh my comparator since there is no stopping at my breakpoints there.

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you've shown looks good at first glance, so the problem must be somewhere else. Can you add a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: is there a typo in your `GetHashCode`? should that be `car.Id.GetHashCode()` ?

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point in your `IEqualityComparer`?

Comment: I've fleshed it out into a runnable example, and it works fine. Maybe show what you're doing different to this? http://pastie.org/5365261

Comment: Are you sure you have cars in both your inputs?

Comment: Have you tried to materialize your query `var updatedCars = CarsList.Intersect(dbCarsList, carsComperator).ToList()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try iterating through the result list. If Intersect uses yield return mechanism, it will initiate comparison only when resulting IEnumerable is iterated through.